# Protocol is not seem to be found on Swift 4.0

Tags: objective-c, protocols, swift-protocols, swift4

My framework is encountering weird behavior on Swift 4.0. The implementation of my framework is as following.
It is written in Objective-C, and the implementation of XXXProtocol is defined in another file in same framework and its header file is under **Project** group at Build Phases.

```
@protocol XXXProtocol;
@interface XXXObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView<XXXProtocol> *XXXView;
@end
```

When I use this Protocol from application, XXXView can be recognized on Swift 3.2 but can not be on Swift 4.0. Why is this happen? Are there any changes around Protocol on Swift 4.0?

FYI:
If I move the Protocol's header file to **Public** group, XXXView can also be recognized on Swift 4.0.

EDIT:
In addition to the above, I should have added `#import "Header-File-Protocol-Defined.h".`

Comment: So, your `protocol` is defined in your framework and you are using this framework in another project. Right?

Comment: @nayem Yes, it's right.

Comment: Well then, the behavior you are encountering is right. When the header files are under **Project** group, they can be found on the same project. But if you want to use some resources in another project, you have to expose them under **Public** group.

Comment: @nayem This does not explain, why it worked under 3.2, does it?

Comment: I guess (yes, it is guessing, the change of rules in Swift is not overviewable) that the rules, how Swift produces the identifier from the Obejctive-C identifiers, changed. `XXX…` does not seem to be a good property name in Objective-C, too. However, did you try to give a Swift name to the property using `NS_SWIFT_NAME`?

Comment: @nayem `XXX` is sample code and I am using another prefix actually, sorry. And I have never tried NS_SWIFT_NAME.

Comment: Of course, what I wanted to say, was unclear. Let's say `XXX` is your prefix like `WHAT`, than your property should not have that prefix. This is, because class interfaces opens a separate name space.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad No it doesn't. But the principle is absolutely right. Might be it was a bug in Swift 3.2 and is resolved in 4.0. I don't have enough understanding into framework's settings.

Comment: @nayem Yes, using Swift, such assumptions are valid. Simply wanted to say, that this is not a complete explanation. However, you posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Yes I got your point.

Comment: Thanks men, my previous code was actually wrong and it might be compiled because of bug in Swift 3.2, thus I should fix my code now. Am I understand right?

Comment: This is *one* possible solution. You shouldn't give up right here. Did you try `NS_SWIFT_NAME`?